# Java DateTimeFormatter can't format its own parsed TemporalAccessor

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time

I'm creating a simply DateTimeFormatter, but it can't seem to read it's own output. The reason I need to use the DateTimeFormatter directly and not LocalDate.format or YearMonth.format is that the code needs to be generic enough to handle different instances of DateTimeFormatter with completely different fields. The code below fails with: `java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: YearOfEra`

```
DateTimeFormatter yearMonthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM");
TemporalAccessor yearMonthTemp = yearMonthFormatter.parse("200102");
String formatted = yearMonthFormatter.format(yearMonthTemp); //fails here trying to format its own output
```

Is there any way to accomplish the above without having to know the contents of the datetime pattern? i.e. the string "yyyyMM" is not static, it will be passed as a parameter.

Edit: Dang, asked and solved in 40 minutes, on a Saturday.

Comment: So why do you need this to work? This might be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: If one needed to change the format of a Temporal without knowing the formats head of time, eg from yyyyMM to MMM-yyyy, you would need two different DateTimeFormatters. The formatters would be completely compatible in terms of the fields that they parse and the temporal objects they produce. But if one of them can't format its own result then it certainly won't be able to format a result from the other.

Edit: Enforcing /  handling compatibility failures would be on the user/caller to handle. But this isn't a compatibility failure, it's my use/understanding of the API.

Comment: I realize this could be done by literally checking the presence of fields to ensure compatibility of LocalDateTime, YearMonth, LocalDate, etc. But that seems like avoidable complexity and it feels like there must be a way to get a DateTimeFormatter to understand that the temporal has all the fields necessary to format the object.

Comment: So you are allowing the user to send in a year, an hour of day, an offset from UTC, and you expect them all to be handled uniformly? You may still want to give us a hint why you need this.

Comment: The input is pairs - e.g. ("yyyyMM","MMM-yyyy") , ("MMMdd",ddMM"). Both of those pairs meet the requirements that I stated in that they are compatible with one another. The 'why' is that I need to change the date format from a large set of possible formats to a smaller set of standard formats. Neither set is defined at compile time.

Comment: You may solve it by using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)`. Not sure whether it will give you problems with other inputs, though. What happened was that the default “smart” resolver style interpreted 2001 as ISO year (signed), so java.time was not able to extract a year-of-era from it after that. The “strict” resolver style prevents such an interpretation.

Comment: @OleV.V. That does indeed solve it! I was aware of the LENIENT style but I was not aware of the Year/YearOfEra differences between SMART and STRICT styles. Strict is actually what I need anyway because the Era field is not supported, thus the years can be assumed to be in the same Era.

Comment: Doesn't happen with uuuuMM

Comment: @g00se That's a good point, that I could simply use "u" instead of "y". It was just a bit confusing that a Formatter could not format its own result, but that's due to the SMART ResolverStyle mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening here is that when you parse the string, an additional [resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#resolving) phase happens, and turns the `yyyy` format specifier representing the "Year Of Era" temporal field into a "Year" temporal field in the returned `TemporalAccessor`, and you end up with (`yearMonthTemp.toString()`):

```
{Year=2001, MonthOfYear=2},ISO
```

When you format, the `yyyy` format specifier expects to format a "Year Of Era" temporal field, but the temporal accessor doesn't have it, as you can clearly see above.

> If one needed to change the format of a Temporal without knowing the formats head of time, eg from yyyyMM to MMM-yyyy, you would need two different DateTimeFormatters. The formatters would be completely compatible in terms of the fields that they parse and the temporal objects they produce.

If all you want to do is changing formats, you can set the resolver style to `STRICT` (by default this is `SMART`):

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM")
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
```

Though I cannot find documentation for this, I have found that this will prevent it from automatically changing "Year Of Era" to "Year" (which is typically denoted `uuuu`). From my testing, every parsed temporal field will be present in the result. Assuming that you have the same format specifiers in the formatting `DateFormatter`, it will get the same temporal fields successfully.

Note that this also means that you cannot easily get something like a `YearMonth` from this `DateTimeFormatter`, because `YearMonth.parse`/`YearMonth.from` expects a "Year". not "Year Of Era".

```
// does not work
System.out.println(YearMonth.from(yearMonthTemp));
```

Comment: This solves the problem. The limitations you mentioned might definitely be relevant to anyone else that runs into this, but for my usage I think this will work since the very nature of the code is that I won't be using those partial date classes.